# How to let pytest rewrite assert in non-test modules

Tags: python, pytest

We defined all our custom assertions in a separate python file which is not a test module.

For example:
`custom_asserts.py`

```
class CustomAsserts(object):
    def silly_assert(self, foo, bar):
        assert foo == bar , 'some error message'
```

If we use `assert` directly in tests, we will get extra info about the AssertionError, which is very useful.

Output of directly use assert in tests:

```
>       assert 'foo' == 'bar', 'some error message'
E       AssertionError: some error message
E       assert 'foo' == 'bar'
E         - foo
E         + bar
```

But we found that if we call the assertion method we defined in separate module, extra info won't show.

```
from custom_asserts import CustomAsserts
asserts = CustomAsserts()
def test_silly():
    asserts.silly_assert('foo', 'bar')
```

Output after running the test:

```
>       assert 'foo' == 'bar', 'some error message'
E       AssertionError: some error message
```

And we also found this in pytest docs: [Advanced assertion introspection](http://pytest.org/latest/assert.html#advanced-assertion-introspection)

> pytest only rewrites test modules directly discovered by its test
>   collection process, so asserts in supporting modules which are not
>   themselves test modules will not be rewritten.

So my question is, is there a way to let pytest do the same assert rewriting to other modules just like test modules? Or is there any hacky way to achieve that?

Answer (score 20):

Update:

Pytest 3.0 introduced a new method `register_assert_rewrite` to implement this exact feature. If you are using pytest 3.0 or later, please try this. [register_assert_rewrite](http://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html?highlight=pytest.register_assert_rewrite#pytest.register_assert_rewrite)

Original answer:

It's kind of wired to answer my own question but I think I found the solution and want to share.

The trick is in how pytest collect test modules. We can define `python_files` in `pytest.ini` so that pytest will consider more modules as test modules.

For example, in my case, all my custom asserts module ends with 'asserts', so my `pytest.ini` is:

```
[pytest]
python_files = *asserts.py test_*.py *_test.py
```

Another tricky thing is in `conftest.py`. It seems we have to avoid import the asserts module in `conftest.py`. My assumption is that it looks like the technology pytest uses to rewrite assert is actually rewrite `.pyc` file, and since `conftest.py` is loaded before collecting, if we import the asserts module, `.pyc` of the module would be generated before collecting, which may make pytest unable to rewrite the `.pyc` file again.

So in my conftest.py, I have to do thing like:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=Ture)
def setup_asserts(request):
    from custom_asserts import CustomAsserts
    request.instance.asserts = CustomAsserts()
```

And I will get the extra error info just like using keyword `assert` directly in test script.

Comment: [Answering your own question is fine, even encouraged!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) The Web UI even suggests that you might want to write your question and immediately answer it, just as a method of documenting and sharing something important you discovered while developing software.

Comment: Can you please share an example?

Comment: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html?highlight=register_assert_rewrite#pytest.register_assert_rewrite

Comment: While this is the correct answer to the question, I thought I'd add that if you have the option, you can move the helper function into conftest.py which is registered for assert rewriting by default