# pytest assert introspection in helper function

Tags: python, pytest

`pytest` does wonderful `assert introspection` so it is easy to find differences in strings especially if the difference is in white space. Now I use a slightly complicated test helper that I reuse in many testcases. The helper has its own module, too and for that module I want to add assert introspection.

**helpers.py:**

```
...
def my_helper():
    assert 'abcy' == 'abcx'
```

**test_mycase.py:**

```
from .helpers import my_helper


def test_assert_in_tc():
    assert 'abcy' == 'abcx'


def test_assert_in_helper():
    my_helper()
```

test report shows helpful information for asserts within tests but `not for asserts within the helper`:

```
=============================================================== FAILURES ================================================================
___________________________________________________________ test_assert_in_tc ___________________________________________________________

    def test_assert_in_tc():
>       assert 'abcy' == 'abcx'
E       assert 'abcy' == 'abcx'
E         - abcy
E         ?    ^
E         + abcx
E         ?    ^

tests/test_pytest_assert.py:9: AssertionError
_________________________________________________________ test_assert_in_helper _________________________________________________________

    def test_assert_in_helper():
>       my_helper()

tests/test_pytest_assert.py:13: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

    def my_helper():
>       assert 'abcy' == 'abcx'
E       AssertionError

tests/helpers.py:258: AssertionError
======================================================= 2 failed in 0.24 seconds ========================================================
```

As a workaround I output additional info with the assert but the output still looks weird and makes the code blow up. Any ideas how I can activate pytest assert introspection within the helper file?

I found a [different, but related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134430/how-to-let-pytest-rewrite-assert-in-non-test-modules) unfortunately I could not get the solution working so far:

```
import pytest
from .helpers import my_helper
pytest.register_assert_rewrite('helpers.my_helper')
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had to put the `register_assert_rewrite` into `tests/__init__.py` like so:

```
import pytest

# we want to have pytest assert introspection in the helpers
pytest.register_assert_rewrite('tests.helpers')
```

Comment: While this is the correct answer to the question, I thought I'd add that if you have the option, you can move the helper function into conftest.py which is registered for assert rewriting by default.

Comment: @mcarans That's extremely helpful advice when you are stuck on a pytest version old enough to not support this answer's solution!

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work correctly when you have several `assert` in the helper :(

Answer (score 2):

Set the `python_files` configuration in `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
python_files = python_files = tests/*.py tests/**/*.py
```

For more info see [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-python_files)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73104019/5506988)

The benefit of this approach is that it works for existing and new code without having to manually register each module - provided the regex matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
[pytest]
python_files = tests/*.py helpers/*.py
```

Worked for me, as helpers have the code where actual assertions exist.