# Pytest assertion doesn't show differences on AssertionError

Tags: python, pytest

I recently learned about using *Pytest* for doing unit tests in Python. I've played around with it in [Repl.it](https://repl.it/) by doing a simple assertion on two different strings which should fail.

```
import pytest
assert 'a' == 'b'
```

Which fails with the error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 2, in <module>
AssertionError`

However Pytest does not print 'a' or 'b'. This would be really helpful in debugging as I can compare the diff between 2 different strings. The *unittest* module has this feature by default. Does Pytest have this feature? If not how do I enable it? I'm using Pytest for a larger project and would love to figure this out before continuing work.

Comment: You have to run that module with pytest, not with regular python!

Comment: So if I run `pytest main.py` on the command line I will see the value of the strings? What about in my larger project, which is an AWS lambda function in python? How would I see the strings then?

Comment: Yes, you have to run ``pytest main.py``. I have no idea about AWS lambda - I don't think it is meant for running standalone applications. ``pytest`` is a unit testing framework, it is not meant to be used in regular code.

Comment: `pytest` is to execute tests, not scripts. If you create a script whose name starts with `test_` and inside a function whose name starts with `test_`, `pytest` will find and execute it. See [this repl](https://repl.it/@hoefling/so-53001496) for a working example.

Comment: My script does start with ```test_``` and my function does start with ```test_```. I know that ```pytest``` is finding and executing my test but I'm looking for a way for pytest to output the difference between two strings on an AssertionError.

Comment: probably this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522767/pytest-assert-introspection-in-helper-function

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Also see [assertion rewriting](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/writing_plugins.html#assertion-rewriting) if your assertion code is in an external helper function.

This was an issue for me, but fixed by adding `pytest.register_assert_rewrite('path.to.helper')` in the `__init__.py` in the test directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot! What I still did wrong, was the path. So the whole path from the content root is needed.