# Expected results of Assertion Errors are not showing up when using Pytest and conftest.py file

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I am using Pytest to test my website content.  I have a fixure in my conftest.py that creates a webdriver for other tests to reference.  When an error occurs during a test run, only `AssertionError` is displayed, as opposed to the actual and expected values being tested in the `assert` statement.

Here is my conftest.py file:

```
import os

import pytest
from selenium import webdriver


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def setup(request):
    driver_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'drivers')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    session = request.node
    for item in session.items:
        cls = item.getparent(pytest.Class)
        setattr(cls.obj, "driver", driver)

    yield driver
    driver.close()
```

Here is my high-level test file:

```
import pytest

from validations import *


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class TestOurServices:
    def test_our_services_direct_navigation(self):
        go_to_our_services(self.driver)
        validate_our_services_content(self.driver)
```

Then here is an example of the output:

[image]

Comment: By chance, does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522767/pytest-assert-introspection-in-helper-function

I wasn't quite able to replicate the error, I think it may be something in `go_to_our_services` or 'validate_our_services_content'

Comment: Yes this helped tremendously!  Thank you @JackThomson.  I didn't realize that you had to use that "register_assert_rewrite" function if you are using assertions in helper functions outside of the direct test case.  I will post the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post helped solve the issue:

[pytest assert introspection in helper function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522767/pytest-assert-introspection-in-helper-function)

I had assertions in helper functions such as `validate_our_services_content` from above.  They were in a file called `validations.py`

Referencing the above issue I created an `__init__.py` file to declare those validations:

`__init__.py`

```
import pytest

pytest.register_assert_rewrite('validations')
```