# Problems with assert when using helper method in pytest when starting tests trough PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

If the second parameter of assert is used normally it prints it out debug information.
E.g. with the following code:

```
class TestTest:
    def test_test(self):
        assert 1 == 2, "TEST"
```

The following debug information is printed:

```
tests\test_test.py:1 (TestTest.test_test)
1 != 2

Expected :2
Actual   :1
<Click to see difference>

self = <tests.test_test.TestTest object at 0x000002147E5B1B08>

    def test_test(self):
>       assert 1 == 2, "TEST"
E       AssertionError: TEST
E       assert 1 == 2
E         +1
E         -2

test_test.py:3: AssertionError
```

However, if the assert happens in a helper function, this is not printed:

```
class TestTest:
    def test_test(self):
        self.verify(1)

    def verify(self, parameter):
        assert 1 == 2, "TEST"
```

results in:

```
tests\test_test.py:1 (TestTest.test_test)
1 != 2

Expected :2
Actual   :1
<Click to see difference>

self = <tests.test_test.TestTest object at 0x000002AFDF1D5AC8>

    def test_test(self):
>       self.verify(1)

test_test.py:3:
```

So the stack trace is incomplete and the debug information not shown.

UPDATE:
This only happens when starting the test through PyCharm (2021.3).

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522767/pytest-assert-introspection-in-helper-function

Comment: Which version of pytest do you use? With version 6.2.5 I can't reproduce incomplete stack trace.

Comment: I've updated to 6.2.5, same problem, but I noticed it doesn't happen when starting pytest trough the  command line instead of trough PyCharm, Question updated.

Comment: In PyCharm settings, which is your testing default test runner? (in File | Settings | Tools | Python Integrated Tools)

Comment: it says autodectect (pytest)

Comment: PyCharm calls pytest with a bunch of quieting options:`pytest --no-header --no-summary -q`. Does [the solution shown in this other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73873315) help?

Comment: Indeed, this works. The only drawback is that you have to click on "Test Results" to see the assert diff. It is not captured in the output of the failing test itself.

Answer (score 1):

Pycharm has some quieting options, such as `pytest --no-header --no-summary -q`

They can be configured:
File > Settings > Advanced Settings and then checking the `Pytest: do not add`... I think you'll understand.

Comment: It’s a shame that you have to click on the top level "Test Results" to see the output… (not captured in the output of the failing test itself)