# How to remove pytest --no-header --no-summary -q parameters in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

I see the parameters for running a default-settings `pytest` configuration are as follows:

```
Launching pytest with arguments payments/tests/test_edd_countries.py --no-header --no-summary -q in payments/tests
```

I would like to remove all of those parameters specifically:

```
--no-header --no-summary -q
```

How can that be achieved given the `Runtime configuration` in `Edit Configurations` does not even show them?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The parameters `--no-header --no-summary -q` are added as an IDE setting (they aren't set in *Run Configurations*).

They can be configured by going to `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Advanced Settings` `>` `Python` and checking the option `Pytest: do not add "--no-header --no-summary -q"` as shown in the screenshot:

[image: IDE settings]

Comment: How's *that* for a bit of trivia.  thx

Comment: @WestCoastProjects there already many Qs about [costumizing "run configurations" for pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[pytest]+[pycharm]+is%3Aq+run+configurations). I checked and this Q about removing the default params is unique on SO. So I edited the original question to narrow the scope. If you need something more specific do a search and if there aren't any hits ask a new question. (TBH I had asked myself this same question many times but had never gotten the right push to go looking for a solution!) Good question!!

Comment: spelunking the `advanced settings` was not anticipated in this context - thus the comment about "trivia" .  while i was at it all the other advanced settings were perused: good to do that from time to time in an editor/IDE where many hours are spent every week