# How to get pytest to register_assert_rewrites for all modules under tests/ directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have a project like:

```
/app
    /app
        foo.py
        bar.py
    /tests
        __init__.py
        core.py
        test_foo.py
        test_bar.py
```

In `core.py`, I have some functions that call `assert`. These functions are imported into test_foo.py and test_bar.py.

Calling `pytest test_foo.py` by default will not pretty print any of the values used in the `assert`, if the `assert` was called from a function imported from `core.py`.

One way around this is to add the following to `tests/__init__.py`:

```
import pytest
pytest.register_assert_rewrite('tests.core')
```

However, this is inconvenient as you would need to add every module from your tests directory into this call.

Is there a way to get pytest to do this automatically, without me having to specify each module I want pytest to rewrite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pretty asserts are thanks to Pytest's Assertion Rewriting mechanism. Its [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/writing_plugins.html#assertion-rewriting) states:

> ... this hook only rewrites test modules themselves (as defined by the
> python_files configuration option)

So one thing you could do is to change your `core.py` file into `test_*.py` (like `test_core.py` or `test_core_utils.py`), which is the standard pattern of files that pytest is translating.

Another option would be to change the `python_files` configuration in `pytest.ini` like so:

```
[pytest]
python_files = test_*.py core.py
```

See more about it [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-python_files).

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I can just do `python_files = tests/*.py`