# How to properly use the 'pytest_assertion_pass' hook to count all assertions that pass

Tags: python, pytest

I'm attempting to count the number of assertions that pass in a `pytest` run, but the hook only appears to be firing for a few tests.

As can be seen from the output, I have 43 test items, each of which has at least one assertion.

The [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_assertion_pass) states "Use this hook to do some processing after a passing assertion." To me, that suggests that the hook should fire after every assertion, but that is not the case.

How can I properly count all assertions that pass?

#### `pytest.ini`

```
[pytest]
enable_assertion_pass_hook=true
```

#### `conftest.py`

```py
assertion_count = 0

def pytest_assertion_pass(item, lineno, orig, expl):
    global assertion_count
    assertion_count += 1

def pytest_terminal_summary(terminalreporter, exitstatus, config):
    print(f'\n{assertion_count} assertions tested.')
```

#### Output

```py
platform linux -- Python 3.10.6, pytest-7.3.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/user/project
configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: cov-4.1.0
collected 43 items                                                                                                                                                                                                    

az/test/colours_test.py ...............................             [ 72%]
az/test/logging_test.py ............                                [100%]

5 assertions tested.
```

---

## Update

I have written a suite of assertions functions, and it seems that `pytest` doesn't count an assertion as passed if it passes out side of a `test` function.

The 5 assertions I was seeing were because I'd missed one test function and was directly using `assert`.

So the question has evolved to why does `pytest` count a passed assertion like this...

```py
def test_one():
    assert 1 == 1
```

but not like this...

```py
def assert_equal(expected, actual):
    assert expected == actual

def test_two():
    assert_equal(2, 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I understood the problem I was able to search for a solution, which happily was very simple. All I needed to do was add `python_file` to `pytest.ini`, making sure that I include all Python files from my test directory that start or end with `test`, and the file that contains the custom assertions.

```
[pytest]
python_files = test/test_*.py test/*_test.py test/assets/assertions.py
```

Source: [How to let pytest rewrite assert in non-test modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134430/how-to-let-pytest-rewrite-assert-in-non-test-modules)