# How to access a variable defined in a conftest hook from an external function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I'm trying to get the number of assertions passed using a pytest hook as shown below. The variable that keeps track of this number is defined in conftest.py. This implementation works perfectly fine as long as the count is printed within conftest. But when I am trying to access this `assertion_count` variable in an external test function, the counter is getting updated but the correct value is not available in the external function.

Reference:
[How to properly use the 'pytest_assertion_pass' hook to count all assertions that pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76472009/how-to-properly-use-the-pytest-assertion-pass-hook-to-count-all-assertions-tha)

```
# conftest.py
assertion_count = 0

def pytest_assertion_pass(item, lineno, orig, expl):
    global assertion_count
    assertion_count += 1
```

```
def external_test_function():
    print(f"Total Assertions Passed: {assertion_count}")
```

I tried using a fixtures approach but still no avail.

Any help in accessing the `assertion_count` in an external method is appreciated.

Comment: Where/How are you running this `external test function`? Is it part of a pytest run?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have in `pytest.ini` file:

```
[pytest]
enable_assertion_pass_hook=true
```

And then you'll need to unlink the `.pyc` files in your project directory and interpreter libraries after enabling the option, as assertions will be need to be re-written again.

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -delete
```

If you haven't cleared .pyc since enabling the option, it will just look like 0 assertions were counted.